# How can I get rid of the “The target assembly contains no service types” for self WCF hosted projects

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with several WCF self hosted projects. Every time i run a uni test i message box  with this message pops up.

Because the projects were not created as WCF projects,  they don't have the WCF tab in properties page were, according to many posts, i should be able to fix it by disabling option `Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution`

I am running on VS 2017.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Found out.
The problem was that i had a WCF Library project in the solution that was created as a regular Library project.

I fixed by adding the followin XML tag to the library project:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}">
        <WcfProjectProperties>
          <AutoStart>False</AutoStart>
        </WcfProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

To get the tag, case anyone wonder what is it, i created an WCF library project on a dummy solution, uncheck the `Start WCF Service host when debugging another project in the same solution` as show in the picture below, and grab the tag from the config file.

[image: WCF Options Tab]